# Sails.js, get request params a json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sockets, sails.js

I am using sockets in Sails.js

Following is a sample client code:

```
socket.get('/message/send', {from: userId, to: recepientId, content: textMessage});
```

And this is how I get data in the controller(Server):

```
    var to = req.param('to');
    var from = req.param('from');
    var content = req.param('message');
```

Now since I am sending the data as a json, i want to get it as a json object. So Message is eventually a model, and I want to store the data in the db directly using the json object.

Similar thing works for me when I use `socket.emit('channel',{userId: "someId"})`
So I do receive a JSON object in `socket.on('channel', function(userJsonObject){});`

So how do I get a similar JSON object when I use `socket.get()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why it's so important, but something like

```
socket.get('/message/send', {
  message: JSON.stringify({from: userId, to: recepientId, content: textMessage})
});
```

should work.

Comment: thanks for the answer, just found out, the following is working fine:

    
`socket.get('/message/send', {messageDetails: {from: userId, to: recepientId, content: textMessage}});`